# Как обрезать лишние символы перевода строки в конце текста?

Tags: база-данных, oracle, plsql

Как мне обрезать в PL/SQL символы перевода строки (клавиша <kbd>Enter</kbd>) в конце текста?

```sql
DECLARE
    A VARCHAR2(32000) := 'какой-то длинный текст..';
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(RTRIM(A, '.'));
END;
```

Этот код обрежет точки в конце текста, а мне нужно обрезать символы перевода строки.

Comment: А что такое "ENTER" ? У вас в примере его нет.

Comment: когда заполняли  базу, в конце текста нажали enter, что при выводе на шаблон передвигает все мои линии..

Answer (score 3):

Как и все остальные символы, указать в списке удаляемых символов:

```sql
declare
    a varchar2 (32000) := 'какой-то длинный текст '||chr (10)||chr (10)||chr (13);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line (a);
    dbms_output.put_line (rtrim (a, chr (10)||chr (13)));
    dbms_output.put_line ('конец');
end;
/
какой-то длинный текст 


какой-то длинный текст 
конец
```

Подробнее в [офф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/RTRIM.html#GUID-95A7DAFB-F7AB-48F4-BE24-64B3C7A840AA).

Comment: Ах, точно, блин! 
Я совсем забыл "chr (13)" же..

Comment: Спасибо огромное.. 
завтра на работе попробую, должно сработать..

Comment: Рад был помочь! Попробуйте, что сработает нет никаких сомнений. Если кто-то в середине текста тыкал Enter, то задайте новый вопрос, там будет другое решение. При случае, посмотрите в справке [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Спасибо что помогли..
Ах точно, если по середине кто-то добавить enter, то как будет??
Скажите, я заинтригован.. 
Тоже добавлю, а вдруг и так добавить enter, и мне же придется все сделать же..

Comment: А вот еще, как сделать такое:
declare
a varchar(32767) := 'Какой-то текст с разной длины';
dbms_output.put_line (substr(length(a), 10));

Comment: А вот еще, как сделать такое:
declare
a varchar(32767) := 'Какой-то текст с разной длины';
begin
dbms_output.put_line (substr(length(a), 1, 10)); -- выводит от начала до 10 символ текста (но мне надо последнего слово не надо обрезать, как дойдет до пробела его надо выводит на след. строке.)
dbms_output.put_line (substr(length(a), 10)); -- А здесь выводит все остальные символы
end;

И вот здесь мне надо последнего слово не обрезать надо а чтоб на след. строке вывел вместе с остальными

Comment: Мою фразу - _Если кто-то в середине текста тыкал Enter, то задайте новый вопрос, там будет другое решение_  вы не совсем поняли. Оформите новый вопрос кнопкой [Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). В комментарии можно попросить уточнить только по текущему вопросу.